# Utilizing browser-history from within an iframe

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iframe, routes, angular-ui-router

I have an AngularJS app running within an `iframe`. The app provides its own navigation (using `ui-router`) and the surrounding page does hardly contain anything except for my app.

Thus **i would like it to be possible to navigate my app by using the browser-back/forward buttons**.

## Current behaviour

When I navigate back/ forward or refresh my page, this only affects the parent page (full reload). This makes sense because a state-transition within my iframe does not affect the URL and thus does not create a new entry within the browser-history.

## Research

What's weird is that on my search for a solution i found several questions about how to **prevent** an iframe from messing/ interfering with the browser history. Thus I assumed that generating browser-history on state-changes was some kind of default behaviour.

I played around with

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode
```

and the urls within my state-objects, but nothing seems to actually affect the browser-history.

I assume that once i solve this, the next step would be to prevent a full page-reload on browser-navigation and instead invoke a `$state`-transition within my app. It seems like i need to utilize the `iframes` `popstate` event for this, but didn't find any documentation or good examples on this yet. Can you point me in a good direction on this?

## Question

How can I **delegate** (back-/forward-)**browser-navigation** to an Angular-App which is running inside an `iframe`?